# SQLAlchemy joins table from subquery. How to prevent it of doing this?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, orm, flask-sqlalchemy

I have this subquery:

```
aliasBilling = aliased(Billing)

subQueryReversesBilling = db.session.query(BillingReversal).select_from(BillingReversal).with_entities(BillingReversal.reverses_billing_id).filter(BillingReversal.billing_id == aliasBilling.id).subquery()
```

Which generates:

```
SELECT billing_reversal.reverses_billing_id
FROM billing_reversal, billing AS billing_1
WHERE billing_reversal.billing_id = billing_1.id
```

How to get rid of that join(comma style) I didn't specified as it makes a join for the full table and every record. Apparently it is assuming I need it as it is in the filtering part(where clause), but I take that table from the bigger query I have later on. That is why it is a subquery. What I need is this:

```
SELECT billing_reversal.reverses_billing_id
FROM billing_reversal
WHERE billing_reversal.billing_id = billing_1.id
```

Comment: Could you share the models `Billing` and `BillingReversal` to see how they are related ?

Answer (score 0):

The cross join is coming from the aliased Billing table in the filter clause.

If  `BillingReversal` and `Billing` are linked with a relationship (and a foreign key), you should leverage this relationship and `join` instead of `filter`.

```
subQueryReversesBilling = (
    db.session.query(BillingReversal)
        .join(Billing, BillingReversal.billing)
        .with_entities(BillingReversal.id)
        .subquery()
)
```

Comment: Done the explicit join. Not working because I still need the filter part as I need to filter according to the main query as it is a subquery. Still adding the cross join.

Comment: Could you share the whole query then, it would be easier to understand what solution you need.